# Non-trivial way to recalculate positions after a switch of values

Tags: mysql, math

I have a MySQL table with items classified with ranks:

```
fruit     rank

banana     1
apple      2
cherry     3
raisin     4
pawpaw     5
```

Let's do a little switch, changing pawpaw to position 2. Here's the table I want:

```
fruit     rank

banana     1 # Unchanged
pawpaw     2 # -3
apple      3 # +1
cherry     4 # +1
raisin     5 # +1
```

If I do this to banana, to position 3. I expect to have this table:

```
fruit     rank

pawpaw     1 # -1
apple      2 # -1
banana     3 # +2
cherry     4 # Unchanged
raisin     5 # Unchanged
```

Doing an algorithm to acheive this is not very complicated. However, I've done it in a very trivial and non-optimized way:

1. Get everything in the fruit table;
2. calculate new ranks in PHP with a bunch of conditions;
3. update the fruit table with new ranks.

Is there a single optimized MySQL UPDATE command which can do this?

Or, alternatively, is there a mathematical formula for this sorting problem to avoid using lots of conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest storing the ranks as 10, 20, 30, and so on, rather than 1, 2, 3.

Then, you can move `pawpaw` up with the query:

```
update items
     set rank = 15
     where fruit = 'pawpaw';
```

You can re-normalize the values using:

```
set @rn := 0;

update items
    set rank = (@rn := @rn + 10)
    order by rank;
```

Comment: Smart solution. I think the second request should be `update items
    set rank = (@rn := @rn + 10)
    order by rank;` though, to keep a 10 stages ranks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two UPDATE queries:

```
UPDATE table
   SET rank = to_rank
 WHERE fruit = 'pawpaw';

UPDATE table
   SET rank = rank + IF(from_rank > to_rank, 1, -1)
 WHERE rank BETWEEN IF(from_rank > to_rank, to_rank, from_rank) AND IF(from_rank > to_rank, from_rank, to_rank)
   AND fruit <> 'pawpaw'
```

Here with first query you move item you want to new position. And with the second one you renumber items between old and new position.

Comment: @fancyPants Did you read the whole query? It contains condition `fruit <> 'pawpaw'`